# Dynamically importing modules do not show variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

Normally if you import variables this way:

from Class1 import *

you will be able to write out all the variables that are in that module.
But if i want to import dynamically the variables dont show.

Is there a way to show the variables even if the module was dynamically imported?

```
Selected_Class = "Class1"
__import__(Selected_Class)
print(variable_in_Class1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep reference of the import, let's assume u have 2 files:

bar.py

```
foo = __import__('foo')
print(foo)
print(foo.foo)
```

foo.py

```
foo = 'foo'
```

Executing bar, prints:

```
<module 'foo' from 'foo.py'>
foo
```